How to Measure Temperature Difference in Fluids?
I have an assignment, in which I have to measure the difference of temperature between the base and the surface of a fluid (e.g. oil) that is being gently heated from its bottom, in order to explain the convection currents.
I have access to common school science lab apparatus, so any suggestions to measure the difference in temperature accurately would be appreciated.
Moreover, I wanted to ask how can I measure temperature using IR Thermal Camera Module? My school has IR Thermal Sensor but I don't know whether it would work for thermal imaging. I am on a low budget, so any idea of how to implement it at low-cost would be a great help.

I would just use a pair of thermocouples. They are cheap and accurate.

Bore a hole in the bottom of your box, than introduce a thermometer or other measuring device, of cause you have to seal the hole around your thermometer. The second thermometer at the top is easy.

If you use a pair of thermocouples, per John Rennie's suggestion, first take simultaneous measurements of the same temperature over the expected temperature range that you are measuring a difference for, to ensure that both thermocouples are actually reporting the same temperature.  I am making this recommendation because you are looking for a small temperature difference and small errors in different thermocouple readings will lead to large errors in temperature difference.

See the latter posts of the following thread:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/moving-an-adiabatic-partition-in-an-adiabatic-container.981529/
